# jQuery - smooth scroll to div

Tags: jquery, scroll

Hi i've wrote some code that scrolls page to an element after click but before smooth scroll it jumps to the top of the page. Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong ?

this is the script

```
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
       $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('body').offset().top
       }, 1000);
       window.location.hash = '';
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - $(this).height()
        }, 1000);   
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
    }
        return false;
});
```

and tell me where can i learn JS :) please

Comment: Go thro' following links for learning and Mastering JS  :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687566/learning-javascript-in-one-weekend

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Comment: What is the reason for putting this line `window.location.hash = ''`? Have you tried without this line?

Comment: yes i've tryed many configurations of it but it still "jumps" in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is html of menu

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="top">
    <ul class="menu_list">
      <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
      <li><a href="#o_nas">About</a></li>
      <li><a  href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is modified script for the menu

```
//menu smooth scroll to element
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function(e){
        $target = $(this).attr('href');
       e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if($(this).attr('href') == '#') {

           $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $('body').offset().top
           }, 1000, function(){location.hash = $target;});
        } else {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($target).offset().top + 57 - $('.menu').height() 
//this is important to add + height of menu holder div in my case it's 57 this removes jump effect in firefox
            }, 1000,function(){location.hash = $target});

        }
        return false;
    });
```

i've solved my question and this is it, the above code works perfect to me and i'm putting it here for other programmers like me ;) and we got the single page site with url change and smooth scrolling effect :P

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial and demo shows how to achieve that. Take a look at it. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: this isn't what i'm looking for my script works great in chrome but in firefox it doesn't work properly. url is changing but after scroll it jumps to the element and after click it jumps to the top of the site