# Auto scroll text effect

Tags: jquery, loops, scroll

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do the effect that's used [on this page](http://gridelicious.net/themes/treble/demo/#) on the 'Hello Treble' text? It seems to be an auto scrollbox text animated with a loop with jquery or something like that but I'm not sure how to do it.

If anyone has the solution, it would be very appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have just used

jquery.bxslider.js

You can read its documentation here:

http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create it by any vertical slider script. Just use text instead of any image.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this **[jquery-smooth-scroll-to-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986416/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-div)**. this is my script and it changes the url after scroll

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function(e){
        $target = $(this).attr('href');
       e.preventDefault();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if($(this).attr('href') == '#') {

           $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $('body').offset().top
           }, 1000, function(){location.hash = $target;});
        } else {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($target).offset().top + 57 - $('.main_menu').height()
            }, 1000,function(){location.hash = $target});

        }
        return false;
    });
```